# CKEditor 5 InlineEditor -- How to configure toolbar?

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar, ckeditor5

I am experimenting with CKEditor 5 InlineEditor.  I would like to modify the toolbar to add additional options.  For example the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
InlineEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#personal-life', {
        toolbar: [ 'headings', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
    } ) )
    .catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );
</script>
```

It still shows the default toolbar and not the one specified.  The examples in the documentation show the ClassicEditor.  Is it possible using the InlineEditor?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Edit:  As written, there is a typo.  The toolbar object should be the second argument to .create not the second argument to .querySelector.  As written the editor works fine. except for the toolbar problem.  When the typo is fixed it doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a js fiddle and it looks like everything is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9vthmvLc/.

```
<div id="editor">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>

InlineEditor.create(
  document.getElementById( 'editor' ),
  {
    toolbar: [ 'headings', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
  }
);
```

The fiddle uses CKEditor 5 downloaded from CDN. I've also tested it locally with a zip download.

Keep in mind that underline is not included in default builds, so I removed it from your toolbar configuration. Maybe that's why you were confused. [Here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/issues/51) and [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/editor-recommendations/issues/4#issuecomment-321217761) is some explanation on not including underline in default builds. If you really need it for some reason, consider [creating your own build](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html).

Comment: Thanks.  All the examples I saw were for the classic editor.  I assumed the InlineEditor had similar functionality.  Newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the options which are available for customizing the toolbar of your specific build by hitting `F12` to open developer tools in your browser (while navigating in a webpage which has the toolbar you want to customize), then clicking `console` and running the following code:

```
Array.from( editor.ui.componentFactory.names() );
```

You will get a result similar to this one:

```
Array.from( editor.ui.componentFactory.names() );
(21) […]
0: "undo"
1: "redo"
2: "bold"
3: "italic"
4: "blockQuote"
5: "ckfinder"
6: "imageTextAlternative"
7: "imageUpload"
8: "heading"
9: "imageStyle:full"
10: "imageStyle:side"
11: "indent"
12: "outdent"
13: "link"
14: "numberedList"
15: "bulletedList"
16: "mediaEmbed"
17: "insertTable"
18: "tableColumn"
19: "tableRow"
20: "mergeTableCells"
​
length: 21
```

You can then use each of these options in the `toolbar` array:

```
 toolbar: [ 'undo', 'redo', ...],
```

It works for any kind of toolbar, either inline, classic or else.